# Quickly switch between most recently used (or last/previously used) font in word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

The majority of the document I am writing uses exactly two fonts: The default font that is used for the current theme + style and Courier New. Is there a way to quickly switch to the first Recently Used Font in the font pull-down without having to *use* the font pull-down? It is breaking my work flow when I have to constantly move to the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create styles for the fonts and [use the keyboard shortcuts](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/assign-style-keyboard-shortcuts-word-2010-2007/) for that.